# OneNote Links with a # won't open in IE 11

Tags: onenote

I'm using OneNote 2010. I am creating links that contain a hash `#`, for example `http://a.com/index.html#MainMenu`. When clicked, the address sent to IE 11 is changed to `http://a.com/index.html%20-%20MainMenu`. I have tried changing the `#` to `%23` but the link fails to load entirely then as my intranet apparently doesn't support encoding. I've seen other posts that state there's a way for the support for encoding to be disabled server-side.

Has anyone heard of this and know of a workaround? Prior to being forced to upgrade to IE 11 this functioned properly when clicking links in OneNote.